# Placing a div over advertising instead of below

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-ads-api

I have this code:

```
<div class="c1">                                    
  //code that makes a div move downwards                     
</div>  
<div class="banner">        
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

  <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:200px;" ....>
  </ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>        
</div>
```

in div class c1 there is a div that scrolls down when clicking on a button. If instead of the google ads code there is

```
<div class="banner">        
<img src="...">       
</div>
```

The div is over the top of the image as it should be. But with google ads, the ad is not covered.

How to place the div above google ads?

Comment: Try `display: block` on your div

Comment: @Coulton this is the default display for DIV

Comment: True, but it sounds like one of the divs isn't block level anymore?  I don't know without seeing the actual implementation.  Any chance of a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Coulton I added `style="display: block;"` to <div class="c1">, tried, removed it from there, added it to <div class="banner">, tried, same result

Comment: Try with `z-index:9999`

Comment: @Danko  That's too much!

Comment: @ManofSnow it isn't too much because ads of google has huge values see this https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/1249219?hl=en and this https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2408599?hl=en

Comment: Ohhh you meant 'over the top of' or 'covering' not 'above' !!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make these changes it should work

```
<div class="c1" style="position:absolute;z-index:2147483647">                                    
  //code that makes a div move downwards                     
</div>
```

Comment: No!  This is terrible, why set the `z-index` so high?!?!

Comment: that is the maximum value of the z-index. to make sure that it goes on top

Comment: So?  There's a better solution!  Get the element with the highest z-index and **+1** it!  And what do you mean, ***'code that makes a div move downwards'?***  He said when clicking a button, and that's not where it would go!

Comment: haha may be :) but this is a better solution ;) it eliminates the process of "Getting the element with highest z-index and +1 it" and still works !